# Adding different handler in single Jetty server

Tags: java, websocket, jetty

I need a jetty server with multiple servletHandler.

HTTPservlet:

```
    ServletHandler servletHandler = new ServletHandler();
    server.setHandler(servletHandler);
    servletHandler.addServletWithMapping("com.realtime.webserver.MyServlet", "/MyServlet");
```

WebsocketServlet:

```
MyWebSocketHandler myWebSocketHandler = new MyWebSocketHandler ();
             myWebSocketHandler.setHandler(new DefaultHandler());
             server.setHandler(myWebSocketHandler);
             server.start();
```

I need both should be in single server.
Is there any possibilities?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You can use org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection (Jetty 9)

```
HandlerCollection handlerCollection = new HandlerCollection();
handlerCollection.setHandlers(new Handler[] {servletHandler, myWebSocketHandler});
```

Later add handlers to the collection:

```
handlerCollection.addHandler(newHandler);
```

Finally,

```
server.setHandler(handlerCollection);
server.start();
```

Comment: Hey. I followed your advices, I can go to my servlet, but when my WebSocket is opened, I receive the Error "Received unexpected compressed frame", and closes.
How can I change ports of my handlers in order they work on a different channel and don't disturb each other?

Answer (score 4):

http://git.eclipse.org/c/jetty/org.eclipse.jetty.project.git/tree/examples/embedded/src/main/java/org/eclipse/jetty/embedded/ManyHandlers.java

This is an example of using many handlers at once on the same server.

Eventually it will be added to the documentation here:

http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/embedded-examples.html

Until that time there are many other examples there that should help make things clearer as well.